# When I click on the ext of the anchor tag it isn't taking me to another page

Tags: html, css, anchor

When I click on the ext of the anchor tag it isn't taking me to another page

```css
.section2 {
  display: flex;
  height: 60vh;
  z-index: -100;
}

.left {
  background: url('builder.jpeg');
  width: 50%;
  border: 6px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  background: url('village.jpeg');
  border: 6px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  /* opacity: 0.5; */
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="section2">

  <div class="split left">
    <a href="builder.html"> click me</a>
  </div>

  <div class="split right">
    <a href="village.html"> click me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code in the anchor tags aren't taking me to another page

Comment: what happens when you try clicking on the `a`?

Comment: Try ./file.html

Comment: where are those files located on your server?

Comment: Make sure that both files `builder.html` and `village.html` are present in the same folder where the main HTML file is.

Comment: What does "click on the ext of the anchor" mean?

Comment: ext was a typo error! sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative `z-index` of `.section2`, `.left` and `.right` are sinking the anchors into the "background" making them unclickable.

Comment: @Nav, if you'll accept the answer it will help others in your position find what they need.